# Set OpenFileDialog to default to Thumbnail view

Tags: .net

I'm using the OpenFileDialog class so a user can select an image file.  I'd like to default the dialog to Thumbnail view mode.  Unfortunately the class doesn't have any way to set a default view mode.

Other than creating my own custom dialog (which I may have to do), is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code project article is what i used a while ago to extend the OFD and SFD, it also links to some other articles which have more detailed explanations

[Extend Open and Save File Dialogs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx)
[More in depth article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx)